# How/Why does factoring the linear/differential operator suggest a specific change of variables?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, differential-operators, change-of-variable

> Find a solution of the PDE $u_{tt} - c^2 u_{xx} = 0$, (where $c$ is a constant) in the half plane $t > 0$ with initial conditions $u(x, 0) = g_0(x)$ and $u_t(x, 0) = g_1(x)$.

$$\therefore \mathcal{L} = \partial^2_t - c^2 \partial^2_x = (\partial_t + c \partial_x)(\partial_t - c \partial_x)$$ *(Linear/Differential Operator.)*

Apparently, this factorisation suggests the change of variables

$$y = x - ct, s = x + ct$$

How/Why does factoring the linear/differential operator suggest a specific change of variables? I see the obvious similarity between the change of variables above and the linear operator of the wave equation, but, speaking in terms of the general concept/theory, this was not explained before this example.

Thank you.

Postscript: Please note that this is within the context of a section on characteristics of second-order PDEs (method of characteristics for Second-Order PDEs).

Comment: Could it be that it should $y = ct - x$ ?

Comment: @denklo Yes! Thank you for spotting that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just give it a try:
$$
(\partial_t+c \partial_x)y = 0 = (\partial_t -c \partial_x)s 
$$

$$
(\partial_t - c \partial_x)y = -2c = -(\partial_t + c \partial_x)s 
$$
which means
$$
(\partial_t - c \partial_x) = -2c \partial_y \text{ and } (\partial_t + c \partial_x) = 2c \partial_s.
$$
This will strongly simplify your differential equation:
$$
\mathcal{L} = -4 c^2 \partial_y\partial_s
$$
which means g only depends on s or y, if $\mathcal{L}g = 0$.

In general, having
$$
\mathcal{L} = (a_{11}\partial_x + a_{12}\partial_t)(a_{21}\partial_x+a_{22}\partial_t)
$$
by the ansatz
$$
y = b_{11}x + b_{21}t \text{ and } s = b_{12}x + b_{22}t
$$
you set
$$
(a_{11}\partial_x + a_{12}\partial_t)y = 1
$$
$$
(a_{21}\partial_x + a_{22}\partial_t)y = 0
$$
$$
(a_{11}\partial_x + a_{12}\partial_t)s = 0
$$
$$
(a_{21}\partial_x + a_{22}\partial_t)s = 1
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
\left(\matrix{a_{11} && a_{12}\\a_{21}&&a_{22}}\right) \left(\matrix{b_{11}\\b_{21}} \right)= \left(\matrix{1\\0} \right)
$$
and
$$
\left(\matrix{a_{11} && a_{12}\\a_{21}&&a_{22}}\right) \left(\matrix{b_{12}\\b_{22}} \right)= \left(\matrix{0\\1} \right)
$$
In other words $(b_{ij})_{ij} = (a_{ij})^{-1}_{ij}$.

Then the transform $y = b_{11}x + b_{21}t$ and $s = b_{12}x + b_{22}t$ will simplify your eqation as above.

Comment: Give what a try? I don’t understand what your answer is saying.

Comment: I'm just suggesting to you to calculate $(\partial_t+ c \partial_x)y$ and the others, to convince youself of $ \partial_t + c\partial_x \propto \partial_y$...

Comment: Hmm, but does that address my question?

Comment: "How/Why does factoring the linear/differential operator suggest a specific change of variables?" : because now you have a new, orthogonal coordinate system wich trivially solves your equation, as i tried to explain in my response.

Comment: I extended my response, does it fit your question better now?

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I think your answer is missing the point. It's just not illuminating. See it from the perspective of the person asking the question. It could be that you're answering it as though to someone who already understands the concept. For example, you say "just give it a try". Give *what* a try? I have no idea what we're trying here: $(\partial_t+c \partial_x)y = 0 = (\partial_t -c \partial_x)s$, $(\partial_t - c \partial_x)y = -2c = -(\partial_t + c \partial_x)s$.

Comment: And then you have this part: "$\mathcal{L} = (a_{11}\partial_x + a_{12}\partial_t)(a_{21}\partial_x+a_{22}\partial_t)$ will map to $\left(\matrix{a_{11} && a_{12}\\a_{21}&&a_{22}}\right) b_i = \mathbf{e}_i$ where $i \in \lbrace1,2\rbrace$ and $\mathbf{e}_i$ is the corrsponding unit vector. In other words $(b_{ij})_{ij} = (a_{ij})^{-1}_{ij}$."

Comment: Someone who reads that, and doesn't already understand the concept, will learn nothing from it. There is no explanation; nothing enlightening towards answering the question "How/Why does factoring the linear/differential operator suggest a specific change of variables?"

Comment: Again, I appreciate the effort, so I don't mean to make it seem like I'm not grateful. Thank you.

Comment: What is $b_i$ in $\left(\matrix{a_{11} && a_{12}\\a_{21}&&a_{22}}\right) b_i = \mathbf{e}_i$?

Comment: It's the first column of $(b_{ij})_{ij}$. Also you don't need to justify your critique regarding my answers. The idea behind the calculation is to find a coordinate system, that derives linearly from $x$,$t$ whose derivatives correspond exactly to the factors of $\mathcal{L}$. Again i slightly adapted my response.

Comment: I think this is on the right track. You've made it clear to me that this phenomenon is true in general and that it is a transformation. Now I only have a few sticking points. What is $b_i$? I'm thinking it's a vector of the values that we are applying the differential operator $\mathcal{L}$ to? And where did $\mathbf{e}$ come from? I know it's the corresponding unit vector, but I don't understand why the LHS equals it?

Comment: Also, what is this: $(b_{ij})_{ij} = (a_{ij})^{-1}_{ij}$? Why is it there?  Then you say, "Then the transform $y = b_{11}x + b_{21}t$ and $s = b_{12}x + b_{22}t$ will simplify your equation as above". But how did $y = b_{11}x + b_{21}t$ and $s = b_{12}x + b_{22}t$ follow from $\left(\matrix{a_{11} && a_{12}\\a_{21}&&a_{22}}\right) b_i = \mathbf{e}_i$?

Comment: I did a last edit last friday. I hope it is now more enlightening. If not, i'm humbely leaving the field to other people to explain...

Answer (score 1):

From your comments it seems like you're more interested in some intuition about why to make that change of variables aside from the similarity of the two? Forgive me if I have misinterpreted. Also the answer of denklo is the more complete one, as I'm really just saying in words what that last eigensystem is saying.

The most intuitive way I grasp it is from a physics perspective: that factorization suggests a type of symmetry, that what happens going leftwards is the same as that going rightwards.

Changing to $x \pm c t$ is to follow the information packets traveling left and rightwards with speed $c$. In physical terms, it's a change of frame of reference to that of the waveform, which because the system has no diffusion or dispersion, must retain its structure.

Comment: Well, I *do* want intuition, but that intuition can also be gained from a mathematical explanation. The problem is that whatever mathematical explanation is provided needs to have sufficient explanation to make it understandable to a person who doesn't already understand the concept.